# How can I change the default profile in Razer Synapse?

Tags: razer-synapse

I use Razer Synapse with my Razer keyboard to control profiles for various uses. Each profile contains different lighting and macro configurations.

Whenever my computer first starts up, or wakes up from sleep or lock, Razer Synapse automatically uses the profile 'TF2' (at the bottom of the list).

[image: The TF2 profile is automatically selected.]

**Is there a way I can change the default profile?** Can I change it to 'Backlit' (the highlighted profile)?

Comment: Related: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11301/are-questions-about-software-for-gaming-hardware-on-topic

Comment: I haven't come across such an option, but I'd be very interested to know if there is one

Comment: @MCΔT So far the only thing that I know of that might work is deleting the profile and re-creating it.

Comment: There are some "solutions" I've found online suggesting binding the profile you want as default to explorer.exe or rzsynapse.exe so it will automatically set itself to that profile on startup. The problem is that if you then switch to another profile and try to use Synapse or Windows Explorer, it will switch back. (I could post this as an answer if it solves your problem, but I don't believe it's a complete solution.)

Comment: angussidney, you should convert your comment to an answer.  I had the same problem and I tried your suggestion and it worked.  It seems like it's the most recently created profile which is the default.  It was driving me crazy since the most recently created one before I did your suggestion was the 'desktop rave' spectrum cycling one :)

Comment: @BrianWhite I would, however deleting a profile and re-creating it can be a big pain if you have lots of macros, lighting configs etc. More of a last resort than a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of profiles is alphabetical, and the last item in the list is always chosen. Just put a Z in the beginning of the profile which you wish to be the default.

Answer (score 3):

I just set my default profile to launch for "explorer.exe" in windows. Just be warned it will switch in the file explorer and any time you return to desktop...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if you actually put A in front of the name instead of Z that solves the problem. I don't know if its mine or yours that is a little odd, but that's what worked for me. Never would have figured it out if you didn't mention the alphabetical thing though, so thanks for that.